# Silverlight Datepicker empty

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have a silverlight date picker declared like below

```
<controls:DatePicker  x:Name="DateFrom"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"></controls:DatePicker>
```

and a button declared as such.

```
<cc:NexButton x:Name="Submit" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="0" Content="Search" MouseLeftButtonUp="NexButton_MouseLeftButtonUp" ></cc:NexButton>
```

When I type a date in the date picker and press the search button without clicking out of the control It will go to the NexButton_MouseLeftButtonUp event.

When I try and get value out by going DateFrom.Text I get "" and when I try and access its selectedvalue by going DateFrom.SelectedDate I get today's date. Both of these cases are wrong and I should be getting the date entered. I thought it might of been a date validation error so I have tried different date formats such as US and UK date formats.

Why can I not access the date entered when I do not click/ tab out of the control? Is some event failing to fire.

Comment: This totally sounds like the TwoWay Binding of the TextBox only updates its source on LostFocus.

Comment: The LostFocus does sound about right.  But I am not using bindings. Is there way to get it to update before its lostFocus?

Comment: Yes there is a way. But before we happily apply all sorts of screwhammers to a nut, let's clarify what is needed: You have a DatePicker, you enter a date by typing. What should happen with the entered date? When? You mentioned a search button, but I can't see a search button in your xaml snippets. What is this search button supposed to do?

Comment: The search x:name is called Submit should be in my xaml above. The date is used as part of a linq query for a date range. Because I cannot get the value that was typed without losing focus the query date ranges are wrong (It ends up trying to return and serialize 200,000 records, each of these having 30 record each.) . When data is returned the data is bound to a list box to display the results. Nothing should happen to the date until you press submit/search and then I only want the inputted value.